# 4.5V AC-DC converter problem

Tags: power, converter

I have been designing a 120V AC mains to 4.5V DC supply. The circuit schematic is shown below.

[image]

After assembling this converter it produced a large spark. Before connecting it I checked for shorts in the soldering.  There are no shorts caused by the board or soldering. The only visible damage I can see on the board is under the hot connection which is connected through a barrier strip. I'm not quite sure what is causing this to happen. I verified this design with the TI Power designer software. Do I have the hot and neutral lines flipped?

Comment: Having hot and neutral swapped on this board will do nothing. What's your board layout look like? How's the isolation?

Comment: If your DC Ground is connected to Neutral or Earth, you will be shorting Line to Ground every second half-cycle.  A direct line-powered supply such as this is hazardous as the output will be a line voltage half the time.  Much better to use a transformer to reduce the line voltage and isolate the circuit from the power line.

Comment: What was connected to it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to be frank here: your design looks **very** dangerous. Please stop working on this design, buy a UL-listed off-the-shelf power supply, and work on other projects.

Here are *only some* of the problems with your design:

- As long as the hot wire potential is lower than ground potential, the lower left diode of D1 will conduct and bring your circuit's "GND" down to the hot wire potential. Possible outcomes:

  - If the outlet this is plugged into is not properly grounded, touching your circuit's GND is likely to **electrocute you**.
  - Even if the outlet is grounded, if the ground wire breaks, then the same thing will happen and potentially **electrocute you**.
  - Even if neither of the above happens, your power supply may draw an amount of power which is too small to trip a breaker, but large enough to **start a fire**.
- The IC that you're using, UCC28881, doesn't seem to have any safety ratings or warranties indicating that it's safe for use in this manner (although it's possible it does have one and I just didn't see it). This means that the IC may malfunction and **electrocute you**.
- The IC also relies on a feedback pin in order to regulate the output voltage. If there is *any* kind of mistake, defect or fault in the feedback circuit, the IC may allow too much current through and thus **electrocute you**.
- Even if your feedback circuit is correctly designed and assembled, a solder joint or something else may crack or otherwise fail some time in the future, which will once again cause the IC to allow too much current through and **electrocute you**.
- There are no fuses between the hot and neutral wires and the bridge rectifier, so if an overcurrent event happens (and please note than an overcurrent event **did in fact happen**), that current may **start a fire**.

Keep in mind that these are *only some* of the problems with your design. There may be other problems that I haven't noticed. Attempting to fix these problems without having a very good understanding of electrical engineering practice could make your design **even more dangerous**.

Comment: Quite so.  Regarding the IC, it doesn't really matter, as the output's common is hazardous voltage anyway; failing and making the output *hazardier* doesn't really add to the calculus.

Comment: @TimWilliams Indeed. But if an isolation transformer were added in the appropriate place, that's probably the next thing I'd worry about.

Answer (score 2):

Swapping hot and neutral won't fix anything.

On one half-cycle of your AC supply, one diode in the bridge rectifier D1 is shorting hot to ground.  If you swapped hot and neutral, it would still happen, but through a different diode.

If you get rid of the ground connection, the problem goes away.

But this circuit offers no isolation from your AC supply.  You should treat *every* part of the circuit as live.  *And that includes anything connected to the 4.5V output.*  A design like this is only intended to be put into a fully insulated enclosure with no way to touch any part of the circuit.  For prototyping things, it's potentially lethal.

Answer (score 1):

You shorted mains to earth through the FWB.  Either lift ground (*circuit is hazardous voltage, do not touch*) or use an isolation transformer.

There is also no protective fusing shown, nor EMI filtering.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is my first time doing this and I haven’t taken any power classes. So if I remove the ac ground line from the circuit it wouldn’t short?

Comment: Correct. However, the output is still a shock hazard.

Comment: @VoxielFox **Please do not remove the ground line.** There are lots of ways this circuit can kill you. I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: I guess FWB = Full Wave Bridge (Rectifier)?